# Sort array of hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have an array of hash like this:

```
[{683=>5}, {689=>2}, {692=>10}]
```

I want the result like this:

```
[{692=>10}, {683=>5}, {689=>2}]
```

Could any one help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). The return value of the block is used as comparison key.

```
[{683=>5}, {689=>2}, {692=>10}].sort_by { |h| -h.values[0] }
# => [{692=>10}, {683=>5}, {689=>2}]
```

Comment: Try `sort_by { |h| h.values[0] }.reverse!`, surprisingly it is slighlty faster and a little clearer, IMHO.

Comment: @toro2k, I just tried it with fruity in Windows 7 64bit, ruby 2.0. It says both are similar.

Comment: On my Debian box fruity reports a 10% difference, well, it seems to be just a little clearer... :-)

Comment: It looks like reverse is faster by 10% for me as well (on osx). I had an array of 10,000 hashes and ran each test 100 times in fruity.

Comment: @toro2k, I got it. Both decorate(in **decorate**-sort-undecorate), `reverse!` take O(n) times. But decorate is performed in ruby loop, while `reverse!` is performed in C. More operations in the block means caused visible time difference.